# HOW-TO questions are treated in different ways

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I can see a lot of HOW-TO questions when reviewing, most of which are asked by new users, and probably will be closed.

Some of them are closed reasonably because the questions are simply "why not working" without even a code snippet.

However a few of them are actually asked properly, the user explains the question well, and shows what he tried. The only "incorrect" thing is that the question is too basic for experienced programmers to answer, to explain it. Then the question will be closed because of "too broad".

Meanwhile, some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048117/how-to-render-large-data-tables-efficiently-with-aurelia) essentially the same as those above, will not be closed just because it's "harder".

My question is: what's the correct way to treat basic HOW-TO questions that is asked correctly?

Comment: *just because it's "harder"* - Well they also included real metrics so that "improve performance" actually means something objective. Most questions that ask how to make something "better" don't specify what "better" means at all, much less giving specific numbers.

Comment: what is "basic"?

Comment: *the user explains the question well, and shows what he tried* - That doesn't mean the question isn't too broad. The text for the Too Broad close reason: *There are either **too many possible answers**, or good answers would be **too long for this format**.* Even a question that's explained well and includes code is too broad if the possible answers are too varied or too long.

Comment: @BSMP true that, but me personally I have trouble understanding what "too long" is in that context. Some of the highest rated answers on this site are almost complete manuals. I tend to interpret the "too long" bit specifically for code you would have to write to complete the answer; if you have to do the OP's work, its too long.

Answer (score 8):

> The only "incorrect" thing is that the question is too basic for experienced programmers to answer, to explain it. Then the question will be closed because of "too broad".

What?  No, this ain't right...

The **only** time a question should be closed for being too broad is if it's *actually* too broad to answer.  If a question doesn't seem to be too broad - that is, it's reasonably scoped, and you feel confident that someone that's knowledgeable in the subject can answer it, then cast a reopen vote if you have to.

I've got my own diatribe on "how to" sorts of questions (which *includes* editing out "How to" and rephrasing it as, "How do I"...as appropriate), and in my experience, it's always fallen in one of these two categories:

- The question is asking a legitimate, "How do I do X?" question, where X is completely unbound or ill-defined.  (XY problems exist here.)
- The question is asking a legitimate "How do I do X?" question, where X is well-defined and well-bounded.

The first ones I close outright, without hesitation.  There's no sense in keeping open a question that's asking how to create a forum or develop an entire database, or worse yet - how they'd go about completing their individual homework assignment.  If it's an XY problem, the closure gives them a chance to reformulate what it was they were asking, and I usually leave a note stating that I'd be willing to cast a reopen vote if they got back on track.

The second ones are the kind that you should be more vigilant for, since there is the potential for a good question.  In the example you've linked to, the reason I feel confident in this sort of question is:

- The problem scope is clearly defined:  they want to improve the performance of Aurelia and its rendering.
- They have provided code an an example that demonstrates their pain point.
- Improving the performance of something would be something that one who is more versed in Aurelia could answer, and as such, that kind of information **should** be exposed and given a chance to surface.  (It's even inspired an answer from one of the core Aurelia developers.)
- Answers to this can be terse.  There's enough code here to play with, and make observations on how its performance can be improved.  There's no need to pull anything from the ether on this one; it's...all there.

These are also the reasons that it shouldn't be closed.  It's on-topic.

The big takeaway you should get from this is that you shouldn't think in terms of a blanket rule for these types of questions.  Every situation that you can't *immediately* rule as off-topic should be handled with a little more diligence and patience.  Take your time to think through the question and see if it really is a question that would require explaining *everything* before the answer would be satisfactory.